# How to get name of class in str type in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, methods, types

How to compare to string of class name like if a variable looks like this `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/etc/passwd' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>` then how can i check if a varaible is equal to this object? This is what I have done but failed.

```py
>>> a = open('/etc/passwd')
a
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/etc/passwd' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> type(a)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> a.__class__
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> a.__class__ == 'io.TextIOWrapper'
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that with the `isinstance` method

```
>>> a = open('/etc/passwd')
>>> import io
>>> isinstance(a, io.TextIOWrapper)
True
```

If you absolutely NEED TO compare by String for some weird reason you can do it like this:

```
str(a.__class__) == "<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>"
```

but unless there is a REALLY good reason to do this, this should never be done like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way, I found out `a.__class__.__name__ == '_io.TextIOWrapper'` works. You can include it in your answer @seven_seas

Comment: Sorry this: `a.__class__.__name__ == 'TextIOWrapper'`